# how to configure defaultDirectory in WindowsFileSystem class

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm using WindowsFileSystem class, and I'm trying to configure some relative paths. Its working but the ***defaultDirectory*** field is set to my apache tomcat bin folder. How to change the configuration for this field?

Comment: Could you give some more details? From the code it looks like it's set in the constructor. I guess Tomcat hand you the object?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `System.setProperty("user.dir", "d:\\dir")`; then relative path in things like `new FileInputStream("1.txt");` will start at `d:\\dir`. If this is what you mean.